# Saving/Accesing Internal Storage, Sony Android TV

Tags: android-tv

I'm trying to save a xml document programmatically inside the Internal Storage of my Sony Android TV. I will also later on will need to accecss this file. Is it even possible to do and how should I approach this? Any suggestions or solutions?

Code:

```
public class xmlCreateFile {
Boolean finished = false;
String TAG = "xmlCreateFile";

public Boolean xmlCreate(){
    try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        // staff elements
        Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
        rootElement.appendChild(staff);

        // set attribute to staff element
        Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
        attr.setValue("1");
        staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

        // shorten way
        // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

        // firstname elements
        Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
        firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
        staff.appendChild(firstname);

        // lastname elements
        Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
        lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
        staff.appendChild(lastname);

        // nickname elements
        Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
        nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mkyong"));
        staff.appendChild(nickname);

        // salary elements
        Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
        salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
        staff.appendChild(salary);

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(path +"/file.xml");


        Log.d(TAG,"Env: " + Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS));
         //Output to console for testing
         StreamResult result2 = new StreamResult(System.out);

       // transformer.transform(source, result);
        transformer.transform(source, result2);

        finished = true;


    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return finished;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a [number of ways](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) to store data on a device. It seems like you only need this information to be visible to your app, so you can use the private [Internal Storage APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal).

These APIs make it relatively easy to store and retrieve a file. Here's a short example.

```
    // Save a file
    String FILENAME = "textfile.txt";
    String writeString = "hello world!";

    FileOutputStream fos = getActivity().openFileOutput(FILENAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(writeString.getBytes());
    fos.close();

    // Read file
    FileInputStream fis = getActivity().openFileInput(FILENAME);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    int inputChar;
    while((inputChar = fis.read()) != -1) {
        builder.append((char) inputChar);
    }
    fis.close();
    String readString = builder.toString();
```

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm, going to try out with the StringBuilder next.